# Embedding fonts not working

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex-spark

Please see the simplest of examples below, this is running as AIR Desktop on windows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        @font-face{
            src: url("C:/Windows/Fonts/AdobeGothicStd-Bold.otf");
            fontFamily: "AdobeGothic";
            fontWeight: bold;
            embedAsCFF: false;
        }

        s|Button{
            fontFamily: "AdobeGothic";
            fontSize: 20;
            color: #000000;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <s:Button label="My Button" />

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

The font is not being used: [image: Spark Button]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html):

> If you set the value of embedAsCFF to false, then the embedded font
>   does not support FTE, and works only with the MX text components.

Furthermore, you're trying to apply a bold font (`fontWeight: bold;`) to a non-bold label. I'm not exactly sure what effect that might have. You may have to do:

```
<s:Button label="My Button" fontWeight="bold"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I had previously tried toggling embedAsCFF but I did not think to set the fontWeight on the button.

Answer (score 0):

one more option, use `dot notation` in your style declaration.

```
.mySparkButton
{
   fontFamily: "AdobeGothic";
   fontSize: 20;
   color: #000000;
}
```

then set your button's

```
 <s:Button label="My Button"  styleName = "mySparkButton" />
```